# Two or more server processes with one SQL Server DateTime flag. How to prevent overlap?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have n number of servers running the same code.

They all use the same SQL server db.

There's a process that needs to be run once an hour by any 1 server.

Is there a way to have a datetime flag in SQL server that could make sure the process is only ever run once an hour by anyone server?

My concern is :

```
if (DateTime.UtcNow > Settings.LastLogDataRetentionCheck.AddDays(1))
{
    await dm.UpdateLastLogDataRetentionCheck(DateTime.UtcNow);

    await dm.CullDeviceLogs();
}
```

What happens if two servers run this code at exactly the same time?

They will both pass the condition and update the DateTime, then proceed to run the expensive process `CullDeviceLogs();`

Comment: You should have your servers obtain some kind of lock so that only one server can run the process. You're trying to fix the symptom instead of the actual problem.

Comment: Yes this is possible.

Comment: you can use Application Lock to control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Squirrel I don't think Application Lock works in a multi-server environment.   At least I can't see that in the docs.

Comment: Think I'm going for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456757/acquiring-lock-c-sharp-sql-server

Comment: You might want to implement 'Optimistic Concurrency'

Comment: @user1443098, I thought this is same server ? `They all use the same SQL server db.`

Comment: From the OP: "I have n number of servers running the same code."